# Check for differnent values between new and old arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values that will get updated periodically. When the array is updated, I want to perform an action using the new values in the updated array.

```
$old_node->field_name[0]['value'] = 'red'
$old_node->field_name[1]['value'] = 'yellow'
$old_node->field_name[2]['value'] = 'blue'


$updated_node->field_name[0]['value'] = 'green',
$updated_node->field_name[1]['value'] = 'red',
$updated_node->field_name[2]['value'] ='purple',
$updated_node->field_name[3]['value'] = 'blue',
```

So the values of 'green' and 'purple' are the new values in the new array. I need to run each of the values that are ADDED to the new array through a function. Something like:

```
foreach(of the newly added values that are in the new array){
 //do stuff;
}
```

Some values may be deleted when the array is updated, so the the key=>value pairs could change.

I've tried:

```
foreach($updated_node->field_name as $new_value){
    if(!in_array($new_value['value'], $old_node->field_name) && $new_value['value'] !== NULL){

    //Do stuff; 

        } 
    }
```

But that doesn't work. I've also tried picking out new values with array_diff and array_intersect, but that's not working either.

Comment: `in_array` should work; but what is `->field_name`?

Comment: the stucture of the array is $node->field_name[0]['value'], $node->field_name[1]['value'],...

Comment: `array_diff` seems to work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JFw647

Comment: @revolt If `in_array`, `array_diff` and `array_intersect` all doesn't work for you, maybe you should `print_r` your original data (`$node`) and see if it meets your expectation...and I suggest you to post an illustration of your actual data structure and code, because your current example seems a little confusing.

Comment: @Passerby Updated the data structure for clarity.

Comment: I've updated my answer since you updated your code. Next time please post actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff)

```
$old_array = array(
          0 => 'red',
          1 =>'yellow',
          2 => 'blue'
);

$new_array = array(
          0 => 'green',
          1 => 'red',
          2 =>'purple',
          4 => 'blue'
);

$diff = array_diff($new_array, $old_array);

print_r($diff);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => green
    [2] => purple
)
*/
```

for your new code

```
$old_node->field_name[0]['value'] = 'red';
$old_node->field_name[1]['value'] = 'yellow';
$old_node->field_name[2]['value'] = 'blue';


$updated_node->field_name[0]['value'] = 'green';
$updated_node->field_name[1]['value'] = 'red';
$updated_node->field_name[2]['value'] = 'purple';
$updated_node->field_name[3]['value'] = 'blue';

$diff = array();
foreach($updated_node->field_name as $num => $field){
    $tmpval = false;
    foreach($old_node->field_name as $old){
        if($field['value'] == $old['value']){
            $tmpval = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$tmpval){
        $diff[$num] = $field['value'];    
    }
}

print_r($diff);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => green
    [2] => purple
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$old_array = array(
          [0] => 'red',
          [1] =>'yellow',
          [2] => 'blue',
);

$new_array = array(
          [0] => 'green',
          [1] => 'red',
          [2] =>'purple',
          [4] => 'blue',
);

$diff = array_diff($new_array, $old_array);
var_dump($diff);
```

That results in

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "green"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "purple"
}
```

which is the correct (expected) result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *simple* function to load up two arrays with the added and removed values:

```
function loadArrayDifferences($before, $after, &$added, &$removed) {
    $added = array_diff($after, $before);
    $removed = array_diff($before, $after);
}
```

and here is a test script:

```
<?php

$ar1 = array(
'one',
'two',
'three',
'four'  

);
$ar2 = array(
'two',
'four',
'six',
'eight',    
);

$adds = array();
$rems = array();
loadArrayDifferences($ar1, $ar2, $adds, $rems);
var_dump($adds);
var_dump($rems);

function loadArrayDifferences($before, $after, &$added, &$removed) {
    $added = array_diff($after, $before);
    $removed = array_diff($before, $after);
}
```

which outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  string(3) "six"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "eight"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
```